# What is the keyword "incr" in the KDevelop IDE?

Tags: c++, keyword, kdevelop

I just downloaded [KDevelop](http://kdevelop.org/) because it scans header files to offer better suggestions in code completion.
I was looking at all the keywords it suggests when no header files are included at all:
[image]
Why is it recommending "incr"?
That's not a C++ keyword.

---

What is it, and what is it used for?
I thought it might be short for increment..?

Comment: What happens when you select it? Maybe it becomes `++i`?

Comment: In Tcl incr is the same ++ operator from C.  I haven't heard before about the existance of the incr operator in C.  Maybe KDevelop displays operators for other languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's a bug. Looking at KDevelop source, `incr` has been add for code completion in file `languages/cpp/codecompletion/context.cpp` on line 2326. It looks like a synonym to increment operation, however only valid synonyms are: `and (&&), bitand (&), and_eq (&=), or (||), bitor (|), or_eq (|=), xor (^), xor_eq (^=), not (!), not_eq (!=), compl (~)`

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any mention of `incr` as a keyword or alternative token (such as `and` for `&&`) in either C++98 or C++11 so I can only conclude that some other language uses that keyword and KDevelop didn't properly pull in the C++-only keyword set for name suggestions.